# Is it possible to split off a neighbor's Comcast cable to provide service to my condo?

Tags: coaxial-cable

Comcast tech told my tenants that the coaxial cable within my condo was outdated & not adequate to provide good signal so it appears he installed a splitter from my neighbor's downstairs cable and ran new cable up the exterior wall to the M/B for internet service.  Is it possible for a single cable to provide service to my neighbor and my tenants?

Although there is no need for TV modems in the other rooms as tenants are only subscribing to internet service, but if they decide they want to also subscribe to cable TV in the future, would the signal loss with additional splits to the other rooms be an issue? I'm assuming that I would need to run cable from the new outlet in M/B through the wall to other bedroom & then through wall from 2nd bedroom to the living room.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The cable company will run ONE or more cable lines to a structure. Numerous things drive this decision, and I do believe there is a code they also must follow. This is just an FYI.

That said:

The only thing that would actually prevent the provider from splitting off to "other rooms on the same structure" is signal loss and signal quality measurements.

So is it possible to run multiple units from "one service line" via a number of splitters/taps? ABSOLUTELY and this is standard practice.

When the signal degrades beyond a serviceable quality and equipment cannot operate properly, or customers are complaining of outages, they may rerun cables (in near total futility) OR a wise technician will reduce the taps, use boosters, run another drop, etc.

So you know, every time you split a signal there is an inherent loss in dB. Drop below an acceptable level, and equipment will not perform optimally.

Comment: *run another drop*, +1. This isn't DiY, this is call them back out and tell them to send an actual linesmen this time, "because my signal [bleeping] sucks and I'm tired of this [bleeped] BS." - that usually does it.

Answer (score 1):

it's likely that the internal cabling in your residence is RG-59U cable, which is insufficient for today's high-bandwidth services. There are really no code issues with installs such as these, as they fall into the "no-voltage" or "signal" type of wiring. There are code considerations but those have nothing to do with splitting off the line for more than one outlet or more than one client.

As long as the service feed to your shared connection is not the one that would get disconnected for non-payment by the other party, you're in good shape. Design criteria for cable television includes sufficient signal strength for multiple outlets, usually maxed at 4 but sometimes the design allows for only two (a single split) unless additional compensation is performed.

I can see that one leg of the splitter also has attached what appears to be a filter device. This implies that the other party is receiving services that you are not. It's unusual to have this sort of thing readily accessible. It's a simple (and not-legal) matter to remove the filter to access the service. It's also possible that the filter provides only a specific service to your drop. Removing that filter might deny you service.

Comment: My only point in saying anything about code is that there is code that must be followed by the "utility" when bringing lines into, and on to a structure. There are rules to follow.

Comment: Unless you're on really, really old infrastructure, they no longer block signals with physical filters.  Now analog is *gone* (partly to reuse the bandwidth for other sruff, partly to prevent theft), everything is encrypted, and the proprietary, rented box is mandatory. When you buy channels they tell their box to decrypt it for you.

Comment: The condo was built in early 1970's and as far as I know there have never been any upgrades to the original coaxial cable, so very likely it is RG-59 and not RG-6 within walls.  The tech indicated that Comcast doesn't have the equipment to run new wiring down the walls from the attic, so I think that's why they ran new cable that's split off the line from condo downstairs from our unit. I would imagine that it would be fairly expensive to hire a contractor to run new cable within the walls from the attic.

Comment: Harper, there are still filters when a subscriber gets internet only or television only, but usually when it's internet only, to prevent television signals from passing into the residence. With addressable digital television converters and of course, addressable internet cable modems, the filters aren't necessary.